# Веб из PHP в Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Изучил туториалы по Ruby, теперь хочу понять логику (структуру) веб-сайта на ROR. Одним словом, как это все выглядит.

Не могли бы вы переписать этот простой код на PHP, как будто он написан на ROR?

**// HTML/CSS/JS:**

```
<html>
<head>..
<script>
function send(){
var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp(); 
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/send.php', true); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
xmlhttp.send("data=" + $("#test").val() );              

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) 
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
           if(xmlhttp.responseText) alert("Done");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type='text' id='test' />
<button onclick='send()'>OK</button>
</body>

</html>
```

**// Send.php**

```
<?php>

$data=$_POST['data'];

if($data=='1')
  echo true;
else
  echo false;

</php>
```

Comment: Теперь изучайте туториалы по Rails, и сразу станет понятно.

Comment: Что Laravel, что WP, лепились с RoR, под сильным наркотическим воздействием. структура такая же, перешёл и забудь, в reils js и html в одну кучу не сваливают. ruby это японская поэзия.

Answer (score 3):

**Такие простецкие обработчики гораздо проще описать в [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/):**

```
require 'sinatra'

post '/send' do
  if params['data'] == '1'
    'true'
  else
    'false'
  end
end
```

В Sinatra ответом становится то значение, что блок (от `do` до `end`) вернул. В данном случае ответы – просто строки. В Ruby действует "неявный возврат последнего выражения", а значения возвращает почти всё. Интересующий нас здесь `if`, к примеру, возвращает значение, которое вернула выполнившаяся ветка.

В отличие от PHP, какой обработчик (т. е. фргамент кода) будет задействован на запрос, не зависит от расположения файла с кодом в файловой системе. Критерии описываются прямо рядом с кодом самих HTTP-обработчиков (HTTP endpoint). Здесь это определеяет `post '/send'`, накладывающий ограничения на метод (`POST`) и путь (точное совпадение с `/send`).

---

В Rails же, если исключить шаблонный код из `rails new`, сама логика разместится в классе контроллера:

#### `app/controllers/sample_controller.rb`

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController
  def send
    if params['data'] == '1'
      render text: 'true'
    else
      render text: 'false'
    end
  end
end
```

...и поскольку система маршрутизации не опирается на файловую систему, надо указать в файле маршрутов, какие запросы будут передаваться в этот метод:

#### `config/routes.rb`

```
post '/send', to: 'sample#send'
```

Похоже на то, что в Sinatra, только обработчик передаётся не по непосредственному значению (блоком `do`..`end`), а в формате `контроллер#действие` (`controller#action`), да и донастройка дополнительных критериев (динамические сегменты, критерии для параметров, заголовки) выполняется иначе. В общем, проще всего не проводить между ними параллели, а смотреть на эти две системы по отдельности.

По-хорошему, **там ещё мог бы быть класс модели**, но она нужна исключительно для отделения механизма ответа (в контроллере) от **решаемой задачи** (в модели), которая здесь тривиальна.